# Camera Permission getting asked twice

Tags: java, android

So I have an app where I get access on the camera. I am doing all the permission things like described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). In the end when the user denies the access, which happens in the `onRequestPermissionResult` function, I call `onBackPressed`(I also tried `finish`).

Now as expected after I deny the access, I don't get into the camera and go back to my service. Now the permission box appears the second time and I don't understand why, since `onCreate` isn't called anymore after I `finish`, right?

How do I get the second permission box away after I already denied access through the first one that popped.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Kindly share that particular activity code blocks. Otherwise its hard to comment

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the result into shared preferences if they accepted or rejected then you can check if it has been rejected before you call for the request.

Link on shared preferences:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences